# Wordpress Cropped Thumbnails Not Showing

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, crop

I'm trying to display custom cropped thumbnails in Wordpress.

Here is my code:

```
add_image_size('about-us-slider-image', 610, 820, true);
```

And in the front:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($imgID, 'about-us-slider-image');
```

But only original size is shown. Original image is larger than this dimensions and I also tried regenerating thumbnails.

The weird part is that on the server all cropped sizes are visible but not in var_dump() or anywhere else.

Comment: Can you verify your specific image size is actually defined and the image did t actually exist in that size?

Comment: @HowardE yes definitely images are cropped on the server FTP and when I put cropped link manually they show up

Comment: How are you registering the image size? Is it wrapped in a function?

Comment: @HowardE tried in function as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to regenerate the thumbnail after you added this code in function.php then after that it will appear like what you put the size. You have to regenerate by using this plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails-advanced/

Comment: I have already mentioned in description that I tried regenerating thumbnails but it didn't help